# How to check array value is null in ng-repeat using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need one help.I need to check if the array has no value and display one message there using Angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

```
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable">

<thead>
<tr>
<th>Sl. No</th>

<th>Date</th>
<th>
Info(Academic Year,Section,Subject,Semester)
</th>
<th>
Unit Name
</th>
<th>
Lecture Plan
 </th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<div ng-if="viewIncompletePlanData.length>0">
<tbody id="detailsstockid">
<tr ng-repeat="p in viewIncompletePlanData">
<td>{{$index+1}}</td>

<td>{{p.date}}</td>
<td>{{p.session}},{{p.section_name}},{{p.subject_name}},{{p.semester}}</td>
<td>{{p.unit_name}}</td>
<td>{{p.plan}}</td>
<td> 
<a >
<input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-success' value='Update' ng-click="">  
</a>
</td>
</tr>   
</tbody>
</div>
<div ng-if="viewIncompletePlanData.length==0">
<tr>
<center><p><b>No Record Matched</b></p></center>
</tr>
 </div>
</table>
```

In the above code i need when `viewIncompletePlanData` has no value it will display message there `No record found` Otherwise display the array result.Please help me.

Comment: Try this: `<td ng-show='viewIncompletePlanData.length===0'>No record found</td>`

Comment: if >0 no record found ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the length of the array. If the `length > 0` then show the records in table else if array is `undefined` or `length === 0` then show `No Record Found` in the first row of table.

```
    <table>
        <tbody id="detailsstockid">
            <tr ng-repeat="p in viewIncompletePlanData" ng-if="viewIncompletePlanData.length>0">
                <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                <td>{{p.date}}</td>
                <td>{{p.session}},{{p.section_name}},{{p.subject_name}},{{p.semester}}</td>
                <td>{{p.unit_name}}</td>
                <td>{{p.plan}}</td>
                <td>
                   <a>
                     <input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-success' value='Update' ng-click="">  
                   </a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-if="viewIncompletePlanData== null || viewIncompletePlanData.length === 0">
                <td>
                    No Record Found
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by **[ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)** / **[ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)** / **[ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)**

Try like this

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Sl. No</th>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>Info(Academic Year,Section,Subject,Semester)</th>
         <th>Unit Name</th>
         <th>Lecture Plan</th>
         <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="detailsstockid">
      <tr ng-repeat="p in viewIncompletePlanData" ng-if="viewIncompletePlanData.length>0">
         <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
         <td>{{p.date}}</td>
         <td>{{p.session}},{{p.section_name}},{{p.subject_name}},{{p.semester}}</td>
         <td>{{p.unit_name}}</td>
         <td>{{p.plan}}</td>
         <td>
            <a>
            <input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-success' value='Update' ng-click="">  
            </a>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-if="viewIncompletePlanData.length==0">
         <td colspan="6">
            <center>
               <p><b>No Record Matched</b>
               </p>
            </center>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes,its coming but message is coming avobe the table.